# Databinding annotation processor kapt warning

Tags: android, kotlin, annotation-processing, kapt

In my app module's build.gradle, I have added

```
dependencies {
kapt('com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2')
...
}
```

but I'm still receiving the compiler warning for

```
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2'.
```

Everything functions, I just hate having warnings hanging around.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: do you have other dependencies that use annotationProcessor?

Comment: In my build.gradle, all other dependencies are "implementation", "testImplementation", or "androidTestImplementation". I don't know if the 3rd party dependencies I have are using annotation processing.

Comment: Same problem here. Plus I get this error:


e: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding Unable to get public no-arg constructor

Comment: `kapt` is for kotlin and `annotationProcessor` for java code

Comment: @RyanAmaral, I am aware of that, and am using kapt in my build.gradle (above) but still get the warning

Comment: [Solved Databinding annotation processor kapt warning
.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60275454/5788247)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had same warnings until I upgraded to the latest Android Gradle build plugin and Kotlin. Now they are gone. Here is the configuration I use.

*project.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51"
    }
}
```

*module.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // no kapt declaration for databinding here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like the update to 1.2.51 and removing the kapt dependency fixes it

Answer (score 1):

Add following in you `app build.gradle`

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // This one at top where plugin belong to
```

This will do the trick.

`$android_plugin_version` is version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` in `application build.gradle`

Also, add this to your module `build.gradle`

```
android {
    /// Existing Code
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}
```

**You are missing `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` i think.**

Comment: Now: 'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin