# Android Data Binding Issue: The expression XXX cannot be inverted

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, two-way-binding

I'm a newbie for android data binding.
I want to bind multiple SeekBars to a collection of float, such as

```
SeekBar1.progress <---> modelArray[0]
SeekBar2.progress <---> modelArray[1]
...
```

Since the progress of SeekBar is a Int type, I think it would be better to use Converter, and below is the converter code:

```
import android.databinding.InverseMethod
import android.util.Log
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
class Converter {
    @InverseMethod("progressToFloat")
    fun floatToProgress(value: Float): Int {
        val result = (value * 100.0f).roundToInt()
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Int)")
        return result
    }

    fun progressToFloat(value: Int): Float {
        return value.toFloat()/100.0f
    }
}
```

and the model structure looks like:

```
class Model {
 val params by lazy {
        ObservableArrayMap<Int, Float>()
 }
 //....
}
```

and my xml is following:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data class="MyBinding">
        <variable name="Converter" type="com.mypackage.model.Converter"></variable>
        <variable
            name="Converter"
            type="com.mypackage.model.Converter"></variable>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.mypackage.model.Model"></variable>
    </data>
...
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:progress="@={Converter.floatToProgress(model.params[0])}"/>
```

The problem is, every time I build it, it shows :

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****
msg:The expression converter.floatToProgress(modelParams0) cannot be inverted: 
There is no inverse for method floatToProgress, you must add an @InverseMethod 
annotation to the method to indicate which method should be used when using 
it in two-way binding expressions
```

I already refer to lots of website, includes following:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

But I still cannot find out what problem is. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

My development environment

```
macOS High Sierra, 
Android Studio 3.2.1, with compileSdkVersion 28 and gradle 3.2.1
```

**Update:** 
I also try to write Converter as following :

```
object Converter { // change to object
    @InverseMethod("progressToFloat")
    @JvmStatic fun floatToProgress(value: Float): Int { // Add static
        val result = (value * 100.0f).roundToInt()
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Int)")
        return result
    }

    @JvmStatic fun progressToFloat(value: Int): Float { // Add static
        return value.toFloat()/100.0f
    }
}
```

It still does not work.

**Solution**
Ok, I found the problem: My project does not use Kapt.
After add it to build.gradle, all works fine.

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Also, I update my converter body as following:

```
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod("progressToFloat")
    @JvmStatic fun floatToProgress(value: Float): Int {
        val result = (value * 100.0f).roundToInt()
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Int)")
        return result
    }

    @JvmStatic fun progressToFloat(value: Int): Float {
        val result =  value.toFloat()/100.0f
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Float)")
        return result
    }
}
```

If the @JVMStatic removed, the project can compile successfully, but the binding does not work.

Thanks everyone who give my suggestion. I think I just ask a silly question.

Refer to:[Databinding annotation processor kapt warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137564/databinding-annotation-processor-kapt-warning)

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Actually, I try rewrite floatToProgress to floatToString once, since most of the example is convert to string.

Comment: @UmangBurman thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I already try '@JvmStatic' and does not work.

Comment: not `@JvmStatic fun progressToFloat` try `public static fun progressToFloat` in both your functions

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that .. Thanks @tynn

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help, I just update the solution...I really asked a silly question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Ok, I found the problem: My project does not use Kapt. After add it to build.gradle, all works fine.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Also, I update my converter body as following:

```
object Converter {
    @InverseMethod("progressToFloat")
    @JvmStatic fun floatToProgress(value: Float): Int {
        val result = (value * 100.0f).roundToInt()
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Int)")
        return result
    }

    @JvmStatic fun progressToFloat(value: Int): Float {
        val result =  value.toFloat()/100.0f
        Log.i("MODEL", "convert $value to $result(Float)")
        return result
    }
}
```

If the @JVMStatic removed, the project can compile successfully, but the binding does not work.

Thanks everyone who give my suggestion. I think I just ask a silly question.

Refer to:[Databinding annotation processor kapt warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137564/databinding-annotation-processor-kapt-warning)

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that I was trying to make a custom `TwoWay DataBinding Adapter`

but my field in the `ViewModel` class was `LiveData` instead of `MutableLiveData`